# How can i use pipe in this case

Tags: angular, pipe

i have this number coming from my api

`"vlr": 1749109.14`

and i have to formate to show

`174.910.914`

I tried using pipe but I couldn't get the formatting I wanted.

is there a way to get this formatting, or would it be better to change the value coming from the api?

Comment: Are you sure to always receive XXX.XXX.XXX ? Coud you have for example XX.XXX.XXX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me you have 2 solutions :

- 1. Create a function into the service you're receiving this data, and format directly into the service.
- 2. Create a pipe and calculate the value.

1. (service-name)

```js
getData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(...).pipe(
    map(res => this.formatValue(res.vlr))
  );
}

private formatValue(value: number): string {
  let temp = value.toString().replace('.', '');
  return temp.match(/.{1,3}/g).join(".");
}
```

(component)

```js
vlr: string;

constructor(service: ServiceName) {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.vlr = res.vlr;
  });
}
```

---

2. ts

```
vlr = 1749109.14;
```

html

```html
<span>{{ vlr | formatVlr }}</span>
```

(pipe)

```js
transform(value: number): string {
  let temp = value.toString().replace('.', '');
  return temp.match(/.{1,3}/g).join(".");
}
```